# What is the function of "же" in "Как же здесь красиво!"?

Tags: словоупотребление

> Как **же** здесь красиво!
>
> {vs}: Как здесь красиво!

In German, for instance, the words "doch/aber" usually used in the sense of the contrasting "but" can also serve as emphatical flavour particles in exclamative "how (beautiful/big)" contexts.

I wonder if the same goes for the "же" here. And does it have a similar function to:

> Отвечайте **же**!

... though, in this instance, it is coupled with a verb?

Comment: doch/aber is a good comparison.The difference is that in German 'aber' can be used as independent word with conrecte meaning, while же is just a particle (частица) used for emphasis with other words. Compare with French 'mais' - the same idea.

Comment: An emphatic particle. You can do without it. By the way, there's no contrasting.

Answer (score 5):

You're exactly right. *Же* is frequently used in contexts like this, to make the statement more emphatic.